# Is it safe to use jQuery in _Layout.cshtml for a large Angular application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I realise this question is somewhat broad, but I'm hoping I can provide enough contextual detail to narrow it down a bit. In a project I am very new to, one of my tasks is to add a confirmation dialogue when the user clicks the logout link. I have changed the link as follows, in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<div class="row inner">
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "logoutForm", @class = "col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 rightText" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="@Url.Action("CreateNewMlamApplication", "MlamApplication")"><img src="/img/icons/plusIcon.png" class="icon" /></a>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><img src="/img/icons/documentIcon.png" class="icon" /></a>
            @* BKMOD <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()"><img src="/img/icons/gearIcon.png" class="icon" /></a>*@
            <a class="logout-link-confirm" href="#" ><img src="/img/icons/gearIcon.png" class="icon" /></a>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Then, I hook a handler up to `logout-link-confirm`, at the bottom of the layout:

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".logout-link-confirm").click(function() {
                $('#modalLogoutConfirmation').modal('show');
            });
            $(".logout-link-final").click(function () {
                $('#logoutForm').submit()
            });
        });
    </script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

And in the `modalLogoutConfirmation` popup, I perform the actual logout when the user confirms their choice: `$('#logoutForm').submit()`.

This has nothing to do with angular directly, as angular only kicks in on some of the body views in this layout, but it is loaded, and I am a little concerned of any side effects my jQuery may introduce.

Comment: why don't you use modal "directive from angular Ui team instead of Jquery ?

Comment: @sani, because the logout button and modal are outside the scope of the 'ambient' angular app, and I would rather not introduce a second app or meddle with the scope of the main app.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is safe. I'm assuming there isn't any Angular logic involved in the modal itself. Even if there was, you'd have to *intentionally* try to interfere with Angular for any side effects to happen.

Comment: Thanks. My faith in Angular is growing exponentially in learning things like this.